# Eclipse Mantis Error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, mantis

When I try to add my Mantis-Repository (V1.2.12) to My Eclipse Juno with The Mantis Plugin (org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group, V3.8.2) my Eclipse shows this error:

> Unable to load projects : Failed getting projects : Error Type: SYSTEM
>   NOTICE, Error Description: Array to string conversion .

If I continue and try to choose a repository from Mantis, the same error is shown.

My URL is directly pointing to the /api/soap/mantisconnect.php file.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any customisations applied to your Mantis instance? 1.2.12 works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're running Mantis over PHP 5.4, which is not possible for the SOAP API since our SOAP layer - nusoap - does not support it.

My suggestion is to update the latest git version (master-1.2.x) and also install the php native soap version. This will make sure that Mantis will not use nusoap and will works as expected with PHP 5.4

References:

- [Mantis SOAP API documentation](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide/admin.config.soap.html)
- [Bug report for PHP 5.4 support for the SOAP API](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=14157)